# How can I close, restore or minimize DXRibbonWindow when it is maximized?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, ribbon

I'm using the DevExpress libraries (version 12.1) in a WPF project. I need to create a DXRibbonWindow to obtain a RibbonBar alike to the Excel one, on the top with quick access tool bar.

So, the problem is that I can close, restore or minimize this window when it is maximized. These buttons work right when the window is not maximized.

The following code is my .xaml file:

```
<dxr:DXRibbonWindow IsAeroMode="True" WindowState="Maximized" ... />
```

I need to manipulate this window normally. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from [DXSearch](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=maximized%2bIsAeroMode&p=T4%7cP4%7c173&d=15) this issue [have been already reported to DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q430906.aspx).  Current issue status is ***Fixed in version 12.1.8***. So, you are welcome to update your version to that one.

Comment: Thanks. It is a really issue of DevExpress. By the way, do you know how to solved without update to version 12.1.8?